# How to explode incoming sms and insert them into database in php

Tags: php, mysql, function, explode

I have an incoming text in this format:

```
POS;OS0101001;123456;ATAKUMOSA EAST;IWARA;TOWN HALL IWARA;755;650;50;10;10;10;15;245;5;Peacefully conducted ;2018-08-26 07:05:40
```

What I want is to explode the text into something like this:

```
$officer_id = $details[1];
    $userpassword = $details[2];
    $lga = $db->real_escape_string($details[3]);
    $ward = $db->real_escape_string($details[4]);
    $poll_unit = $db->real_escape_string($details[5]);
    $incident_type = $db->real_escape_string($details[6]);
    $incident_priority = $db->real_escape_string($details[7]);
    $incident = $db->real_escape_string($details[8]);
    $device_entry_date = $details[9];
```

I have actually tried to explode it but after the explode, I tried inserting it into the database but it was inserting empty values.

What I tried so far:

```
$dir   = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', substr(trim($_REQUEST['Body']),0,3))));
    $msg   = substr(trim($_REQUEST['Body']),0,3);
    if($dir == 'inc'){
                    onIncidentReport($phone,$date,$msg);
        }
```

To insert into database, I have this:

```
function onIncidentReport($phone,$date,$msg){
   global $db;


       $split  =  explode(";", $msg);
       $details =  strtoupper($split[count($split)-1]);

        $officer_id = $details[1];
        $userpassword = $details[2];
        $lga = $db->real_escape_string($details[3]);
        $ward = $db->real_escape_string($details[4]);
        $poll_unit = $db->real_escape_string($details[5]);
        $incident_type = $db->real_escape_string($details[6]);
        $incident_priority = $db->real_escape_string($details[7]);
        $incident = $db->real_escape_string($details[8]);
        $device_entry_date = $details[9];

       $sql  = "SELECT * FROM master where (phoneNo = '$phone') and regstatus = 1";
       $st   =  mysqli_query($db,$sql);
       $num  =  mysqli_num_rows($st);
       $PtaW =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($st);

        if($num==1){

          $sql   = "UPDATE master SET incmsg = '$incident', incstatus = '$incident_priority', incdate = '$date', 
                    incpriotise = '$incident_priority' where (phoneNo = '$phone' OR phonetwo = '$phone') and regstatus = 1";
          $st    =  mysqli_query($db,$sql);



          $sql   = "INSERT INTO incident 
                   (lgName,phoneNo,msg,status,date) 
                     VALUES ('$lga','$phone','$incident','$incident_priority','$date')";


          $Query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

          if($st || $Query){
            ?>
             <Response>
               <Message>
                 SUCCESSFULLY SENT.
               </Message>
             </Response>
            <?php
          }
        }else {
          ?>
             <Response>
               <Message>
                 YOU ARE NOT AUTHORISE TO USE THIS SERVICE.
               </Message>
             </Response>
          <?php
        }
   }
```

I have tried everything I could. Made some research online but still couldn't figure it out.

Empty values were inserted into the database every time I tried inserting it.

Comment: um, what is the error? also could you `var_dump($details)` and see whats inside?

Comment: @BagusTesa, it's inserting empty values.

Comment: Is error reporting enabled and what does `mysqli_error($db)` on the queries reveal? You're also using the same variable for a few queries which could play a role.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, since it's inserting the date and phone number, it won't return any error.

Answer (score 1):

[strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) returns a `String` object, not an array. `$split` is your array of String that you should use for your DB variables. `$details` is only a single String object returned from `strtoupper()`.

You need to iterate `$split` changing it to upper cases:

```
foreach($split as &$value)
    $value = strtoupper($value);
```

then use the `$split` values in you db variables:

```
    $officer_id = $split[1];
    $userpassword = $split[2];
    $lga = $db->real_escape_string($split[3]);
    $ward = $db->real_escape_string($split[4]);
    //...etc
```

Comment: thanks. I tried it but still inserting empty values.